# sdl linking prolem ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl

I have Ubuntu 14 LTs I'm trying to compile a simple code using SDL library.but i get the answer:

```
game.c: In function ‘main’:
game.c:11:3: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char'but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]  
fprintf (stderr, "could not initialize SDL: %s\n",  SDL_Get_Error());
^
/tmp/ccMGHXqV.o: In function `main':
game.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `SDL_Get_Error'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

tis is my program code compiled with:"gcc  game.c -o game  `sdl-config --cflags`  `sdl-config --libs"

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* my firat game program */

int main()
 {

if ((SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_TIMER|SDL_INIT_EVENTTHREAD)!=0)
fprintf (stderr, "could not initialize SDL: %s\n",  SDL_Get_Error());
printf ("SDL INIZIALIZED\n");
SDL_Surface* screen;

screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0,  SDL_ANYFORMAT|     SDL_FULLSCREEN);
SDL_WM_SetCaption("MyFirstGame", NULL);

atexit (SDL_Quit);
return 0;
  }``
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct function name is SDL_GetError(), not SDL_Get_Error(). See http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError